# Polygamma reflection formula

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, special-functions

How does one prove the polygamma reflection formula:

$$\psi^{(n)}(1-z)+(-1)^{n+1}\psi^{(n)}(z)=(-1)^n \pi \frac{d^n}{d z^n} \cot \pi z $$

Do we have to invoke the power of contour integration and kernels? I searched the web but the proof was to be found nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to prove the reflection formula:
$$ \psi(1-z)-\psi(z)=\pi\cot(\pi z)\tag{1}$$
then differentiate it multiple times. In order to prove $(1)$, let's start from the Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function:
$$\Gamma(t+1) = e^{-\gamma t}\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{\frac{t}{n}}\tag{2}$$
leading to:
$$ \Gamma(z)\,\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}\tag{3} $$
(the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function), then consider the logarithmic derivative of $(3)$:
$$\psi(z)-\psi(1-z) = \frac{d}{dz}\,\log\sin(\pi z)\tag{4} $$
and $(1)$ is proved.

Comment: Wow... Jack... super! I did not think that this formula is SOOOO easy to prove... I thought we would invoke contour integration or apply many acrobatics in order to prove that.. 

Thank you.

Comment: I thought the Weierstrass product follows from the Euler reflection formula not the other way around.