# How to show: $\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) = -\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function, polygamma

Based on a result [I found recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d) and in conjunction with methods I've observed on MSE I was able to show that:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln(t)}{t^n + 1}\:dt = -\frac{\pi^2}{n^2} \operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{n} \right)\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\end{equation}

This is achieved through a simple use of Feynman's Trick. Here we  consider the case when $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $a = 1$:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt = \frac{1}{n} B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) 
\end{equation}
We see that:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dk}\left[ \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt \right]&= \frac{d}{dk}\left[\frac{1}{n}B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right)\right] \\
 \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt &= \frac{1}{n^2}B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{k + 1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) \right]
\end{align}

Thus, 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt = \lim_{k \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{n^2}B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{k + 1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) \right]
\end{equation}

And finally:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt = \frac{1}{n^2}B\left(m - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(m - \frac{1}{n}\right) \right]
\end{equation}

Note: In the case where $m = 1$ we arrive:

\begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^1}\:dt &= \frac{1}{n^2}B\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \cdot -\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}\cdot -\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\end{align}

Thus:
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln(t)}{t^n + 1}\:dt = -\frac{\pi^2}{n^2} \operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{n} \right)\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\end{equation}

Now for the final line I employed [Euler's Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) formula:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}
\end{equation}

The result for the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) expression:
\begin{equation}
\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) = -\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\end{equation}
This was found simply from [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polygamma(0,1%2Fn)%20-%20polygamma(0,%201%20-%201%2Fn)). I did not derive this myself and this is where my question is founded in. I have no idea how to approach this identity. Does anyone have any starting points? and/or solutions?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218786/polygamma-reflection-formula and use the reflection formula on that page.

Comment: @YumekuiMath - Legend. Thanks so much.

Comment: Take logarithm to both sides and then differentiate both sides

Comment: @Digamma - Cheers mate. Will do!